# Is there any way to ignore some other tag when you visit a particular tag?

Tags: support, tag-search

1. I want to browser all the answer with `tag1`
2. such as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1`
3. but there are a list of question with `tag1, tag2, tag3`
4. I have not interesting with `tag3`
5. How to ignore `tag3` when I browser `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1`?

Comment: Search supports the NOT operator; e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btag1%5D+-%5Btag3%5D